# Getting date with JavaScript, then putting it into PHP database - putting actual script not variable

Tags: javascript, php

When I am getting the date from the Javascript, it works fine when I echo it out in PHP, but when I try and insert it into the database, it gives me what is actually between the quotes. How can I fix this?

What it prints out on the page:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZyn5.png)

What it puts in the database:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnpgJ.png)

My javascript/php:

```
$business_date = "<script>var today = new Date(); var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear(); document.write(date)</script>";
```

Thanks,

Comment: The addition of the pictures did not make your question better.....

Comment: You should ask yourself where/when javascript is run, end where the output of the script goes to. The same for PHP, which will have a different answer.    Now your are having a variable `$business_date`, with some string contents. The logic of PHP will tell you that this text will be used, and PHP does not know that this text is a piece of javascript.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, javascript runs in the browser. What you have here is a PHP string variable that does not get interpreted by the browser when you call the database insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrong. Simply - PHP prepare HTML content for browser. Browser make page structure within javascript scripts. Javascript run in browser. If you need push values from javascript, than you must send GET|POST request with this. If you need formated current time or date to db in php, you may use hp functions:

```
/*
 $business_date = "<script>var today = new Date(); var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear(); document.write(date)</script>";
*/
$business_date = strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
```

or you may add current date in database query directly:

```
INSERT INTO table SET `actual_date`=DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: thanks, how would I do this for time as well? hours:minutes:seconds in 24hr

Comment: Got it, strftime('%H:%M:%S');